# Compare two columns with 'LIKE' Operator in SQL / Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to compare two columns from a table. In which i have to check the email is containing his mobile number or not.

```
TableName:- Table1
TableColumns:- id,email,MOB
```

Ex.

SQL:

```
 'SELECT * FROM Tabel1 WHERE email LIKE %MOB%'
```

Laravel :

```
Tabel1::whereColumn('email', 'LIKE','%MOB%')->get();
```

I have Tried this above query but it is showing syntax error.

Comment: Whats is the error code?

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by answering you question SQL-wise, anything in quotes is a literal to SQL, so you need to use column reference and add the wildcard symbols. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%', MOB, '%');
```

Now lets look at Laravel now, the 3rd argument to where expects a literal value not another column. You can overcome this via either **whereRaw** or **DB::raw**:

```
Table1::whereRaw("email LIKE CONCAT('%', MOB, '%')");
```

or

```
Table1::where('email', 'LIKE', DB::raw("CONCAT('%', MOB, '%')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
SELECT * FROM Tabel1 WHERE email LIKE '%' +MOB+'%'
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little more details for why you think your answer can help OP

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `email` LIKE '%MOB%';
```

Comment: IN '%MOB%' , MOB will be considered as string not the Column.